# Spring SAML MetadataManage is null in ArtifactResolutionProfileBase but meta data is loaded correctly

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm having a serious issue that I can't seem to solve.  I've been using the spring boot example here: https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample to integrate a new SP.  Everything was going well when using the HttpMetaDataProvider but recently I had to change to using FileSystemMetadataProvider and things aren't going well.

All of my meta data seems to be loaded correctly but when I do an authentication request I am getting:

org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.resolveArtifact(ArtifactResolutionProfileBase.java:77)

I've debugged through the problem and it looks like the MetadataManager is null in ArtifactResolutionProfileBase, however, I have no idea why and I'm simply stuck!

Here is my config:

```
// Setup advanced info about metadata
@Bean
@Qualifier("idp-extended-metadata")
public ExtendedMetadata idpExtendedMetadata() {
    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    return extendedMetadata;
}

// Setup advanced info about metadata
@Bean
@Qualifier("sp-extended-metadata")
public ExtendedMetadata spExtendedMetadata() {
    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    //sp meta data needs local set
    extendedMetadata.setLocal(true);
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryResponseURL(environment.getProperty("sp.base.url"));
    extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
    extendedMetadata.setSigningKey("student-saml");
    extendedMetadata.setEncryptionKey("student-saml");
    extendedMetadata.setRequireArtifactResolveSigned(false);
    extendedMetadata.setRequireLogoutRequestSigned(false);
    extendedMetadata.setRequireLogoutResponseSigned(false);
    return extendedMetadata;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("ccc-idp")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate CCCIdpExtendedMetadataProvider()
        throws MetadataProviderException, IOException {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource metadatafile = loader.getResource("classpath:" + environment.getProperty("ccc.idp.metadatafile"));
    FilesystemMetadataProvider filesystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(metadatafile.getFile());
    filesystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
            new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(filesystemMetadataProvider, idpExtendedMetadata());
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.initialize();
    return extendedMetadataDelegate;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("student-sp-metadata")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate studentSPMetadata()
        throws MetadataProviderException, IOException {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource metadatafile = loader.getResource("classpath:" + environment.getProperty("student.sp.metadatafile"));
    FilesystemMetadataProvider filesystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(metadatafile.getFile());
    filesystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
            new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(filesystemMetadataProvider, spExtendedMetadata());
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.initialize();
    return extendedMetadataDelegate;
}


// Do not forget to call iniitalize method on providers
@Bean
@Qualifier("metadata")
public MetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException, IOException {
    List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate spMeta = studentSPMetadata();
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate idpMeta = CCCIdpExtendedMetadataProvider();
    providers.add(idpMeta);
    providers.add(spMeta);
    MetadataManager meta = new MetadataManager(providers);
    meta.setHostedSPName(environment.getProperty("sp.entity.id"));
    meta.setKeyManager(keyManager());
    return meta;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a MetadataManager in the artifactResolutionProfile. This worked for me.

You should follow the naming convention and rename the CCCIdpExtendedMetadataProvider method to start with a lower case letter as well.

```
 private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() throws MetadataProviderException, ResourceException {
    final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile =
            new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
    artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
    List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
    providers.add(CCCIdpExtendedMetadataProvider());
    MetadataManager metadataManager = new MetadataManager(providers);
    artifactResolutionProfile.setMetadata(metadataManager);
    metadataManager.refreshMetadata();
    return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }
```